# How will I align the label of a text area to top?

Tags: html, css, forms, layout

I do have  a table data as shown below:

```
<td>
    <label for="title">Title : </label>
    <textarea rows="5" id="title" name="title"></textarea>
</td>
```

the default location for the label is at the bottom. How will I place the label aligned with the top of the text area?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

With the following CSS:

```
​textarea { vertical-align: top; }​
```

- [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aMLFE/)
- [`vertical-align` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/vertical-align):

> The vertical-align CSS property specifies the vertical alignment of an inline or table-cell element.
>
> [What is Vertical Align? on CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/)

Comment: if you have a mixture of textareas and text input fields, this looks a little off, since the label for the input fields will be aligned on the baseline; is there a good css solution for aligning the baseline of the label and the *first* line of the textarea's content?

Comment: @ysth If you play with `vertical-align` (it also accepts length and percentage values), you can get close to that: http://jsfiddle.net/aMLFE/95/ (just an example, it could depend on your styling). Tried it in Chrome, FF, IE11.

Comment: I'm 5 years late, but you can use `line-height` in combination with `vertical-align: top`

Answer (score 2):

@Bazmegakapa Great answer! We can also do it this way

```
label{display:block; float:left;}​
```

fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kaMqg/1/

Comment: Yeah, but floating has a lot of side effects.

Answer (score 1):

Use br tag.

```
<td>
    <label for="title">Title : </label>
    <br>
    <textarea rows="5" id="title" name="title"></textarea>
</td>
```

Comment: this will place the textarea in a new line, not the intended result (check the accepted answer)